# Show subsites under Google website search result

Tags: javascript, html, google-search

How can I make the results of my website look like this on Google search?

[image: Google search result]

I'm not really sure if this is possible in my website, because it's a one page website. If anyone could help and tell me if this is possible, and if it is how is it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links under the main heading are called [Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en). They are automatically generated by google for some websites. [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) allows you to demote sitelinks, but not to add them.

It wouldn't make sense to have Sitelinks to a one page website like yours. If you want them you'll have to add extra pages, and then hope that the google algorithms decide to link to some of them.

Comment: Tanks for the answer. I dint know what they were called so it was harder to find something on the subject. It looks like it was already answered here, sorry. 
I also though it dint make sense in this case, or if it was possible. But i was asked to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) they give a good explanation how to do it.